# Ошибка "PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in..."

Tags: php

Вот код:

```
  $word[$i]=str_replace("*", ", ", $word[$i]);
  $part=explode("=", $word[$i]);
  $part1=str_replace("|", " ", $part[0]);
  $part2=str_replace("|", " ", $part[1]);
```

При его выполнении, если в `$word` содержится выражения типа:

```
[674237234092340234-42348437436::?(*)(_):;№! " " %)(_)]{^%#$@##$^^&*(&~@GVY()(*)(IOU}
```

То возникает ошибка

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  1 in...

которая указывает на строку:

```
$part2=str_replace("|", " ", $part[1]);
```

Собственно, как исправить ошибку?

**UPD**:

Если в `$word` содержится: "В данной строке (`$word`) отсутствует знак", то ошибки не возникает, хотя там нет знака `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данной строке (`$word`) отсутствует знак `=`, поэтому после `explode` в массиве `$part` у вас есть только значение с `0` ключом и выражением `$part2=str_replace("|", " ", $part[1]);`.

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу с индексом `1`, которого не существует, вот и ошибка.

Comment: Опередил... =)

Comment: :) главное попытались оказать помощь, а кто 1-й, кто последний уже все равно. Принят ответ будет на усмотрение ТС, а не по времени :)

Comment: Если в `$word` содержится:
"В данной строке (`$word`) отсутствует знак", то ошибки не возникает, хотя там нет знака *=*.

Comment: Переформулируйте комментарий - ничего ж непонятно

Comment: Ну вот я попробовал определить в `$word` такой текст: "Вася пошел в магазин и купил хлеба", т.е. текст, в котором не содержится знака **=**, но ошибки у меня не возникает. Почему?

Comment: Интересно... что-то в голову не приходит пока. Ну по большому счету, нотис - это не ошибка. А вообще, может лучше переделать скрипт исходя из того что вам нужно. Может, логика работы неправильная.

Answer (score 3):

У тебя в строке

```
[674237234092340234-42348437436::?(*)(_):;№! " " %)(_)]{^%#$@##$^^&*(&~@GVY()(*)(IOU}
```

нет "=", а потому

```
explode("=", $word[$i]);
```

вернет массив с одним элементом, а следовательно $part[1] неопределен.

Comment: Если в `$word` содержится: "В данной строке (`$word`) отсутствует знак", то ошибки не возникает, хотя там нет знака =.

Comment: А как выбирается `$word[$i]`? Это символ в строке `$word`?